# What's wrong with my wiring of this light switch?

Tags: lighting, switch

I am trying to replace a "regular" light switch with one that has a timer built in. The old one, as shown below, on the left, has two black wires attached, and no others.

The new switch requires attaching a hot, load, neutral, and ground. I have attempted to do so, but so far it is not working.

Before:
[image: Before]

Before (side view)
[image: Side view before]

In order to hook up the new switch, I:

- assumed the **bottom** wire of the original switch was the **line/hot** wire and the top was the **load** and attached the wires accordingly. The new switch's red wire is labelled "LOAD" and the black one is labelled "HOT".
- attached the green ground wire to a screw at the back of the electrical box
- pulled a white wire out of the marret of (unused?) white wires to use as neutral, and attached it to the neutral white wire on the new switch.

I had switched my breaker back on for this circuit and the new switch does not work. I have also tried switching the black and red wires, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

After:
[image: After]

Comment: highly unlikely anything is "unused". Do not assume so.  Check around you'll find you disabled something else (light, outlet) as well by disconnecting its neutral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The problem is the neutral**

*pulled a white wire out of the marret of (unused?) white wires to use as neutral, and attached it to the neutral white wire on the new switch.*

Instead you should ADD the new white wire to the existing bundle.  Only ONE is actually a neutral, the rest are other wires that *need* neutral.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! Does everything else sound correct?

Comment: Yep, pretty certain that is your only problem.